# How to fetch categories from mysql into ul?

Tags: php, mysql, database, fetch

I have a mysql database. There are categories in Db for my articles. I want to fetch these categories and display them as a list (side navigation). I was able to establish connection and print the categories but can't put them into the list.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "voltage";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset("utf8");

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully <br>";
$sql = "SELECT ID, NAME FROM categs";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "ID: " . $row["ID"]. " " . "Name: " . $row["NAME"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();    

?>
```

I know it's a dumb question, but I'm PHP newbie.

```
<ul>
    <li>Categ 1</li>
    <li>Categ 2</li>
    <li>Categ 3</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you nearly got it by yourself... try this one:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "voltage";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset("utf8");

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully <br>";
$sql = "SELECT ID, NAME FROM categs";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<ul>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<li>" .$row["NAME"]. "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();    

?>
```

Comment: Yes, thats a good one, thanks. But the thing is that all the li items have one common class and different classes to display different icons for each category. :/ That's the main problem.

Comment: @comcoma Okay, that could become a bit tricky. How many categories do you have? And do you have any field in you mySQL database that defines which icon should be represented?

Comment: <ul id="sidenav" class="list-group">
   <li class="list-group-item shops"><a href="#">Electronics shops</a></li>
</ul>

this is what it looks like. In this case "shops" has appropriate icon. It's done using css. It's not defined in database. Do you recommend adding new column to specify background image (icon) or a class for each category?

Comment: @comcoma Well, lets have a look at your classname. `list-group-item shops` - I think its from something like bootstrap or so, so I think the only thing that will change from `li` to `li` will be the word `shops` - the `list-group-item` will always be there I think? If yes, and if you don't have to much categories, simply add another column in your database, and add all this words like `shops` and so on in the database. Then you can simply do something like echo` '<li class="list-group-item '.$row["columnname.' ">` ... hope you get what I mean, otherwise feel free to ask.

Comment: You helped me a lot. I didn't know '.$row["columnname.' syntax :D . Thanks :).

Comment: @comcoma Well its all about bringing in variables in your echos. For example you can do `echo "Hello {$myvar}";` (Will only work if you open your echo with double quotes so that it gets interpreted as string). Then for example you can do something like `echo "This is ".$myvar."";` and so on. When you get more into PHP you'll learn that quite fast, since you'll see that you can't simply implement variables in your echos everytime. If you ever have another question or want to contact me, simply come back here and write a comment and mention me with @TwinFriends and I'll be here ;)

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
echo "ID: " . $row["ID"]. " " . "Name: " . $row["NAME"]. "<br>";
```

with

```
echo "<li>" . $row["NAME"]. "</li>";
```